# Can't deploy project on Vercel due to name error

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I want to deploy on project on vercel but I keep got an error that say me the project is not valid like this message:

> Error: The name of a Project can only contain up to 100 alphanumeric lowercase characters and hyphens. Learn More

but my name project is: ecommerce_sanity

or this error:

> The name contains invalid characters. Only letters, digits, and underscores are allowed. Furthermore, the name should start with a letter.

for this name project: headphones_ecommerce

I try different name but keep got this error do someone already face this?

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the actual error or copy it entirely

Comment: the two examples I posted are the complete error messages provided by Vercel, it does not give me more explanation.  That's why I don't understand.                                             OPn the learn more link it just say this :  Project names can only consist of up to 100 alphanumeric lowercase characters. Hyphens can be used in between the name, but never at the start or end.

Comment: Check your `package.json` and look for the name field. Does it match `ecommerce_sanity`?

Comment: _"alphanumeric lowercase characters and hyphens"_ - this does not include underscores. Have you tried using hyphens instead: `ecommerce-sanity`?

Comment: @juliomalves, Yes i tried like this too same error.

Comment: @serraosays In the package.json it was only ecommerce but i figured out that it's the environnement variable that make appear the error cause when i try to deploy whithout the env variable but same name it's works so i manage to deploy the project without env variable and add them after.

Comment: If you're deploying to Vercel, define your env up there: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables. Make sure it matches what you have locally in your `.env.local` - remember don't commit `.env.local` to your repo!!!

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was the `env_variables` creating the error. When I tried to copy and paste the env_variables, some spaces were there in the `env_name` like: `HELLO_WORLD`  (note the space at the end) and that was creating this error:

> The name contains invalid characters. Only letters, digits, and underscores are allowed. Furthermore, the name should start with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the project name like "dummy_server" to "dummy-server".
Replace underscore to hyphen. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your github repo like "abc-abc" and it work.  I had the same problem and that fixed it for me.

Comment: You mean use a hyphen rather than an underscore?  They say in the comments that they tried that and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this kind of problem and solved it by using only lowser-case characters. I removed hypens, underscore, numbers, and upper-cases.
And also confirm that your project name is unique. I think your project name could be long.
And one more point, you have to remove un-using projects if you have many project with your basic plan. Or you can upgrade your vercel account to premium one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove underscore and put Hyphen like this

**headphones-ecommerce**

or join them

**headphonesecommerce**

Comment: There are already multiple answers suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a a different error linking my project.

To fix `Error: Project not found`:

- Log into [vercel.com](https://vercel.com)
- From the `Overview` page import project or click `Add new...` if you have existing imports
- Import your repository
- Run `vercel link` once more.